# Final product when sp2 oxygen of acid is O18 in fischer esterification

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters

[image]

In the question above, i was curious about option 3. If the carbonyl oxygen is O18, shouldn't half of the product we obtain contain O18 on the carbonyl since we have two possible leaving groups with equal probability of leaving?

Comment: $\rm^{18}O$ is not radioactive, which might give us some insight as to the level of this quiz and its authors. Your concern is also legitimate. Forget it. Just give them the answer they want.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I understood that and deleted my comment after that. Thank you.

Comment: @AdityaGarg I don't think its possible to isolate O18 as only the carbonyl oxygen. I maybe wrong but I think that since the Acid would be partially(although small) dissociated, i t will lead to resonance between O16 and O18 and thus at equillibrim, the carbonyl oxygen will have both the O18 and O16.